# Overload [] operator basics

Tags: c++

I did this example to understand the use of [] operator but this code is giving me an error
"declaration of operator as array of function", "no match for operator[] in Example[0]" and same different errors like this. Please tell what I am doing wrong and please explain too. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class example
{ 

private:
        double temp[8];
public:
    example () 
    {  
          temp[0] = 3.5; temp[1] = 3.2;  temp[2] = 4;    temp[3] = 3.3; 
          temp[4] = 3.8; temp[5] = 3.6;  temp[6] = 3.5; temp[7] = 3.8;
    }


    double& opeator[] (int Index);
};

double& example::operator[](int Index)
{       
        return temp[Index];        
}


int main ()
{
    example Example;
    Example[0] = 4;

    double temp = Example[4];

}
```

Comment: I'll bet that isn't the first error. There's probably one about trying to declare an array of functions before that.

Comment: You have a typo in "opeator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
double& opeator[] (int Index);
```

is supposed to be:

```
double& operator[] (int Index);
//         ^
```

---

> Please also i didnt understand the use of [] operator properly clearly please also little bit explain that. I read that and did this example to understand but still problem in understanding.

Well, `operator[]` is especially useful to *simulate* an array indexing behavior. The standard library uses this operator on "array-like" classes like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Your example (except for the type obviously):

```
double& example::operator[](int Index) {       
        return temp[Index];        
}
```

is a perfectly fine application of the operator. The only thing I would suggest you to change is the type of the `Index`: it should really be `std::size_t`.

For more informations about *operator overloading*, please, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1).

Comment: Please also i didnt understand the use of [] operator properly clearly please also little bit explain that. I read that and did this example to understand but still problem in understanding.